# visibility hidden flashes multiple times after fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get some text to fade in after some images move once you reach a certain point on the page. It works fine if I am already down the page and I refresh, but when I scroll from the top to the area it does the correct animation but then the text starts to flash over and over again. Is there any way to stop this?

Here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1350) {
               $('#managecontent1').animate({bottom: '0px'},900);
               $('#managecontent2').animate({bottom: '0px'},900,function(){
                        $('#twocolumntextcontainer').css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn('slow');
                   });
           }
                });
        });
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div id="twocolumntextcontainer">
        <div id="twocolumntextleft">
            <p>C.M.S. <span>Wordpress</span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="twocolumntextright">
            <p>F.T.P. <span>FileZilla</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="twocolumnlayout">
        <div id="managecontent1">
            <img src="img/wordpresslogo_203x203.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="managecontent2">
            <img src="img/filezillaicon_210x208.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you please add that HTML portion too? may be a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set conditions that will cause this.

If you take a look, you are triggering the animation every time the window scrolls and the scrollTop value is greater than 1350px. If you continue to scroll at all beyond this point, the animation will continually trigger.

You will likely want to unbind the eventListener as soon as your condition is met (assuming you don't want the animation to happen again until the page is refreshed).

Add this within your if statement:

```
$(this).unbind('scroll');
```

That will unbind the scroll listener entirely from the window once your condition is met once.

Comment: i tried making scrollTop == 1350 and nothing happens at all. even when i scroll to or past that point.

Comment: for some reason it will not recognize  the == 1350

Comment: Just updated me answer to include a better solution. Go take a look and see if that achieves what you're looking for.

Comment: One additional tip: You should likely be using CSS3 Animation for this instead :) My suggestion would be simplify your JS greatly and avoid using JS animation entirely. The solution would instead turn a CSS class on or off depending on your condition. the CSS could handle all the animation for you! Read up on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#twocolumntextcontainer').fadeOut("slow");
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1350) {
                    $('#managecontent1').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 900);
                    $('#managecontent2').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 900, function () {
                        $('#twocolumntextcontainer').fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: i tried that and I cannot use fadeIn on the text because when the images slide in from the bottom they go past the point and then jerk back. I need the div to be there just not visible.